# Выбрать данные из таблицы если в связанной таблице ни одна запись не имеет указанных значений

Tags: mysql

Есть одна таблица примерного вида:

```
id |name
########
1  Name1
2  Name2
3  Name3
```

Вторая:

```
id_from_first_table |id |name |status  |timestamp
##################################################
1                    1   Test1   OK     2016-02-01 11:10:47
1                    2   Test2   OK     2016-02-01 17:10:47
1                    3   Test3   BAD    2016-02-02 12:10:47
1                    4   Test4   ST     2016-02-02 17:10:47
2                    5   Test5   ST     2016-02-03 14:10:47
3                    6   Test6   ST     2016-02-02 15:10:47
3                    7   Test7   OK     2016-02-06 17:10:47
```

Как правильно сделать запрос чтобы получить из первой таблицы только те значение, у которых во второй таблице нету статусов `OK` и `BAD`, но есть статус `ST`. К примеру должно вернуть из первой таблицы только вторую запись. Т.к. для `id=1` во второй таблице есть записи со статусом `OK` и `BAD`, хотя и есть запись с `ST`. Так же и для третей записи. Я так понимаю нужно сделать какой то `Group By` или не так понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
  from table1 T1
 where exists(select 1 from table2 T2
               where T2.t1_id=T1.id and T2.status='ST')
   and not exists(select 1 from table2 T2
               where T2.t1_id=T1.id and T2.status in('OK','BAD'))
```